# Char(39) equivalent in iics taskflow

Tags: iics

I have to migrate some wf infa on prem to iics. In the on prem version in the workflow i have somerhing like that 'select id from test where id =' ||char(39) 'france'||char(39).. i want to know if there is any equivalent of char(39) in iics taskflow expression NOT in mapping expression

I tried to char 39 direcrly but did not work